# Having a problem with mod_rewrite adding a trailing slash

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to turn friendly URLs ( site.com/page/ ) into script friendly ( ?page=page ) That is all working perfectly except for one thing.  If you leave off the trailing slash on the URL it breaks and gets a 404.

I tried using the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133111/mod-rewrite-add-trailing-slash) (slightly modified), but it doesn't appear to be working.  For reference here is my .htaccess rewrite;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks  
Options +Indexes  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#force trailing slashes on real directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^images - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to last/skip on your directory test - as that is what I am guessing - and then you need to modify:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

into either two of them - dealing with the / and non-slash case - or just one

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /?page=$1%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Assuming that that is what you want. You propably want it a bit more likeL

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I've also added a & - as I am guessing you need that too.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  It seems that the best answers are usually the simplest. And yeah, I had just forgotten to add the ampersand and had not gotten to where I was testing any additional parameters, thanks again :)

Comment: Hmm - small warning - the HTML escaper seems to have dropped the '\' backslash in front of the '.' dot. Which is there to prevent .something stuff. In your specific case - a \w or [a-zA-Z] instead of a ^ negate may in fact be safer.